# Comparação entre dois objetos em Python utilizando a função id() com resultado diferente

Tags: python-3.x, idle-ide

Pesquisando, observei que a função `id()` retorna um número inteiro e que garante ser único e constante para o objeto.

Ao comparar dois objetos obtive resultados diferente, o que pode ter possibilitado esses resultados diferentes??

Observei em uma apostila que a comparação `id(Carro()) == id(Carro())` retorna `False` mas ao executar o código o mesmo retornou `True`

Classe Carro.py

```
class Carro:
    pass
```

Código no Idle

```
>>> from Carro import Carro
>>> fusca = Carro()
>>> opala = Carro()
>>> id(opala) == id(fusca)
False
>>> id(Carro()) == id(Carro())
True
```

Comment: Boa pergunta, era para dar `False`, visto que estão sendo criados dois objetos distintos do tipo `Carro`

Comment: Exatamente @Haroldo_OK , aguardar  alguém descrever o pode ter ocorrido.

Answer (score 1):

Na realidade vc não criou duas instancias em:

```
>>> id(Carro()) == id(Carro())  # True
```

por isso da True:

Veja o código abaixo, funciona no python2 ou python3

```
>>> from carro import Carro
>>> fusca = Carro()
>>> opala = Carro()
>>> id(opala) == id(fusca)
False
>>> id(Carro()) == id(Carro())
True
>>> a = id(Carro()) 
>>> b = id(Carro())
>>> a
140356195163608
>>> b
140356195163720
>>> id(Carro())
140356195163608
```